# Java: Print out longest sequence of an integer array. Where's the problem?

Tags: java, algorithm

The task is to let the user input 10 numbers into an array. Then to print out how long the longest sequence of growing numbers is.

So for 1 8 45 6 5 4 5 8 10 65 the longest sequence would be 4 5 8 10 65, which is length = 5

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []a = new int[10];
    int c = 1;
    int max = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      a[i] = In.readInt();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){
      if(a[i]<a[i+1]){
        ++c;
        if(c>max){
          max=c;
        }
      }else{
        c=1;
      }
    }
    Out.print("Length = " + max);
  }
}
```

The program I'm submitting this to says this is only 75% correct and I can't for the life of me figure out why, it works with every combination of numbers I could come up with.

Comment: default value of `max` should be 1. `[ 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ]` <-- max length is 1

Comment: Can you be sure that the values being input are integers and never exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? Is this defined?

Comment: Few things that might be missing:
1) What should happen when the numbers are the same?
2) Should it be consecutive or we just need increasing subsequence. Eg: 1 4 5 8 10 65

Comment: Wow ok the solution was in fact that the default value of max should be 1. Still doesn't really make sense to me as to my understanding, you need more than 1 number for it to be a sequence, but I guess that's more of a semantics question and not really a coding question. Thanks Cid.

Comment: A sequence of 1 is still a sequence, the same way you can have only 1 element in an array

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track, a slight modification of the if condition inside your for-loop by moving the increment of `c` (which I have presumed stands for `counter`/`count`)? inside it should make it work with all test cases:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int aLength = 10;
        int a[] = new int[aLength];

        System.out.printf("Enter %d integers separated by spaces: ", aLength);

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < aLength; i++) {
                a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }

        int maxLength = 1, counter = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < aLength - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i] < a[i + 1]) {
                counter++;
                maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, counter);
            } else {
                counter = 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("Max length is %d\n", maxLength);
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter 10 integers separated by spaces: 1 8 45 6 5 4 5 8 10 65
Max length is 5
```

*Note technically a subsequence/sequence does not have to be continuous (if you were looking the longest subsequence with growing numbers the answer would be 6, i.e., 1, 5, 4, 8, 10, 65) however from what your required output is i.e., 5, it is clear you are looking for the longest sub-array or continuous subsequence/sequence.*